# How to run a Mac OS VM on an Intel Mac?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I'm a developer and some of my users experience issues on older Mac OS versions.

I would like to test my app on an older version of Mac OS using my Intel Mac.

I think the only solution is using a virtual machine because docker only supports Linux guests from my understanding.

Is there any tool to create MacOS VMs and run them on Intel Mac?

Comment: UTM might be a good software for this : [link](https://www.theregister.com/2023/09/29/utm_apple_hypervisor_foss_fest/).

Comment: macOS can only run within a VM on Apple hardware. If you have Apple hardware you should be able to install MacOS on a VM

Comment: Opinion: VMware Fusion is best for running macOS in virtual machines. https://www.vmware.com/au/products/fusion.html But not free for commercial use.

Comment: With some intel boards you might also need to enable virtualization in the BIOS prior to creating a virtual machine.

Comment: @mitchelangelo Not for an Intel Mac - no BIOS.

Comment: @music2myear “I would like to test my app on an older version of Mac OS using my Intel Mac.” This case is valid. It is a modern macOS running older versions of macOS for testing and development. This is not a Hackitosh or similar situation.

Comment: My mistake. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- VMware Fusion works great but is not free for commercial use.
- Virtual Box works but is much slower in my experience.
- UTM targets primarily M1 Macs so without any major investment,
  It won't work easily.